# laravel route not working with contact form

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to create contact form, but unfortunately my routes isn't working.

HTML

```
<form action="con" method="get" >

                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <button>Send</button>

            </form>
```

route

```
Route::get('con', function () {

     return view('services');

});
```

when i click send it doesnt goto the `services` page.
Also, how would it work with the post method?

Comment: <button type="submit">Send</button>

Comment: it didnt work @kenken9999

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf, if you want use method=post

Comment: at least let us know what errors ;) if you install Laravel / web server ...etc incorrect

Comment: every other routes are working except this.

Comment: can you try rename the action  <form action="conn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a name to the route and use the helper function in the action:

```
action="{{ route('con') }}"

Route::get('con', function () {
    return view('services');
})->name('con');
```

For using post, change the method

```
<form action="{{ route('con.post') }}" method="post">
```

And add a route with the post verb:

```
Route::post('con', function () {
    return view('services');
})->name('con.post');
```

As mentioned by others you need a button with a type `submit`:

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried with the post method. following error occur. `You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the filesystem permissions

Answer (score 0):

Add Button Type. `type="submit"`

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

After that in form tag

```
action="{{ route('con') }}"
```

and in route web.php

```
Route::get('con', function () {
    return view('services');
})->name('con');
```